# Sending two exposed filters fast

Tags: views

I'm using auto submit in exposed filter and if I changing the form control twice and fast(Before I'm getting answer on the first change)
I will get wrong view list item.
(So it seems to be that the first ajax request overrules the second selection)
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that because of the auto-submit, you submit an ajax request as soon as the first filter is changed. It then doesn't matter that you make a second change, and the answer to the first request is already being processed.

The only solution that I'm aware of, is to not use the ajax functionality in Views, and instead implement your own, that for example waits one second after changing the first filter before submitting the form, allowing several filters to be changed in one request.